# how do I pass 2 parameters using RewriteEngine in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hello here is what I have :

```
RewriteRule ^page_([^/]*)$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

this works great when the link is domain.com/page_3 it displays page page.php/id=3 . Now I want to pass it this way: domain.com/page_3&u=username. but it keeps saying page not found. I changed that line to this : `RewriteRule ^page_([^/]*)$ /page.php?id=$1&u=$2 [L]`  (doesn't work)
what am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this for 2 parameters

```
RewriteRule ^page_([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  /page.php?url=$1&url2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

And this for three ,and so on and so on

```
RewriteRule ^page_([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$   /page.php?url=$1&url2=$2&url3=$3 [L,QSA]
```